# not read file from ftp

Tags: php, file, ftp

i am trying to read file from but its not reading from particular FTP, but its reading file from another FTP. please check format of username, password and hostname in format i change only text special character remains as my original FTP. 
am using following code.

```php
 $filename ='ftp://uname@abc.com:AAA@&%333aaaa@*&587@ftp.aaaaaaa.com/web_orders/1201931.txt'; 

 $ext = pathinfo($filename,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

 $handle = fopen($filename, "r");

 var_dump($handle);
```

it didn't give any error but not reading file also.

Comment: uname like =  "username@abc.com";

password like = "AAA@&%333aaaa@*&587";

hostname like = "ftp.aaaaaaa.com";

Comment: Replace `@` in username and password with `%40` and `%` with `%25`. I.e. use `'ftp://uname%40abc.com:AAA%40&%25333aaaa%40*&587@ftp.aaaaaaa.com/web_orders/1201931.txt'`

Comment: @MartinPrikryl  , i change in code as you suggest but still showing bool(false)

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, its done thanks.